# 'List' is abstract; cannot be instantiated

Tags: android

The List list = new List (id, name, genre); is given me an error saying "List" is abstract; cannot be instantiated. Not sure what this actually means, looked at a few different answered questions and nothing helped towards fixing this error. Any suggestions or solutions to this frustrating issue please feel free to help.

```
package connect2you.com;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class WindowsPost extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText editTextName;
    Button buttonAddList;
    Spinner spinnerGenres;

    DatabaseReference databaseLists;

    ListView listViewType;

    List<List> listValues;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_windows_post);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        databaseLists = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Windows Thread");

        editTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
        buttonAddList = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAddList);
        spinnerGenres = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerGenres);

        listViewType = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewType);

        listValues = new ArrayList<>();
        buttonAddList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                addList();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        databaseLists.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                listValues.clear();

                for (DataSnapshot listSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    List list = listSnapshot.getValue(List.class);

                    listValues.add(list);
                }

                ListValues adapter = new ListValues(WindowsPost.this, listValues);
                listViewType.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu){

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.menuLogOut){

            startActivity(new Intent(WindowsPost.this, MainActivity.class));
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



    private void addList(){
        String name = editTextName.getText().toString().trim();
        String genre = spinnerGenres.getSelectedItem().toString();

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(name)){

            String id = databaseLists.push().getKey();

            List list = new List (id, name, genre);

            databaseLists.child(id).setValue(list);

            editTextName.setText("");

            Toast.makeText(this, "Post added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this,"You need to enter a title", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
}
```

List Class

```
package connect2you.com;

public class List {

   String listId;
   String listName;
   String listGenre;

    public List(){

    }

    public List(String listId, String listName, String listGenre) {
        this.listId = listId;
        this.listName = listName;
        this.listGenre = listGenre;
    }


    public String getListId() {
        return listId;
    }

    public String getListName() {
        return listName;
    }

    public String getListGenre() {
        return listGenre;
    }
}
```

Comment: Best way to avoid this kind of situation is Rename your `List` class to `Lists` and thee use `Lists` inside your activity class.

Answer (score 3):

Your namespace is cluttered. In the main method, you have the following import statement;

```
import java.util.List;
```

This conflicts with the List class you are intending to use. Either remove the import, or name your List class something else. I recommend the latter, as a List is Java is a widely used interface.

Answer (score 2):

You have imported this:

```java
import java.util.List;
```

So when you try to create a new `List` instance, Java thinks you are trying to do `new java.util.List()`.

You can change the name of your class to avoid the conflict, or create your new instance defining the type explicitly:

```java
connect2you.com.List list = new connect2you.com.List(id, name, genre);
```

To avoid problems and ugly code, I would just probably rename `List` to something else.

Answer (score 0):

Your class List is contradicting with Java Package class.

1. You can either refactor your custom class from List to some other name like CustomList.
2. Or You can specify the package name while creating an instance of your class like

   `connect2you.com.List list = new connect2you.com.List (id, name, genre);`

Answer (score 0):

Rename your `List` class into `Lists` or any name you like

```
package connect2you.com;

public class Lists {

   String listId;
   String listName;
   String listGenre;

public Lists(){

}

public Lists(String listId, String listName, String listGenre) {
    this.listId = listId;
    this.listName = listName;
    this.listGenre = listGenre;
}


public String getListId() {
    return listId;
}

public String getListName() {
    return listName;
}

public String getListGenre() {
    return listGenre;
}
}
```

Import your `Lists` class inside activity

```
package connect2you.com;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import connect2you.com.Lists;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class WindowsPost extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText editTextName;
Button buttonAddList;
Spinner spinnerGenres;

DatabaseReference databaseLists;

ListView listViewType;

List<Lists> listValues;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_windows_post);

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    databaseLists = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Windows Thread");

    editTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
    buttonAddList = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAddList);
    spinnerGenres = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerGenres);

    listViewType = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewType);

    listValues = new ArrayList<>();
    buttonAddList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            addList();
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    databaseLists.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            listValues.clear();

            for (DataSnapshot listSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Lists list = listSnapshot.getValue(Lists.class);

                listValues.add(list);
            }

            ListValues adapter = new ListValues(WindowsPost.this, listValues);
            listViewType.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu){

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.menuLogOut){

        startActivity(new Intent(WindowsPost.this, MainActivity.class));
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}



private void addList(){
    String name = editTextName.getText().toString().trim();
    String genre = spinnerGenres.getSelectedItem().toString();

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(name)){

        String id = databaseLists.push().getKey();

        Lists lists = new Lists(id, name, genre);

        databaseLists.child(id).setValue(lists);

        editTextName.setText("");

        Toast.makeText(this, "Post added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this,"You need to enter a title", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
}
```

I hope this will working for you.